# Bootstrap: Image out of well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

As you can see in this screenshot, the image is out of the .well element.
Here you can see my source code:

```
<article class="well">
    <header>
        <h3>News mit Bild</h3>
        <p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Geschrieben von: <a href="#">TupidaMC</a><br/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Veröffentlicht am 13.11.2014 um 21:23
        </p>
    </header>
        <p class="news-content">... text ...</p>
        <img class="img-thumbnail news-pic" src="http://placekitten.com/g/350/251" />
        <p class="news-content">... text ...</p>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
.news-pic{
     float: right;
}
```

I would like to get some respone.

Comment: Try to add max-width:100% and max-height:100% to the img.

Comment: @shadeed9 thanks but this changes nothing :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a .clearfix class to the article tag.

```
<article class="well clearfix">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zssvdpfd/)

Comment: I feel this should be the accepted answer. If you're using Bootstrap, then use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7681Lstq/

I believe that you are just looking to add `overflow: hidden` to the `.well` element in your CSS.

Comment: @FelixGraf You are most certainly welcome. Feel free to mark my answer correct if you believe it to be the solution.

Comment: I wanted to do it but have to wait for 15 minutes until I can do it :3